# ¿En qué casos no es una buena práctica no declarar un constructor?

Tags: php, poo, buenas-prácticas

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que no declaro constructor y, de este modo, al crear un objeto solo relleno las propiedades que necesite en ese momento. Como ejemplo:

```
class Publicacion{
private $id;
private $usuario;
private $fecha;
private $titulo;
private $contenido;

functions getters();
funtions setters();

function obtener_articulo(){
obtengo articulo a partir solo del id;
return resultado;}
}
```

En este caso, si solo quiero utilizar el método `obtener_articulo()` no hace falta alimentar más que la propiedad `$id`:

```
$publi = new Publicacion;
$publi->set_id($el_id);
$articulo = $publi->obtener_articulo();
```

Siento que es muy útil a nivel práctico pero me pregunto si es una buena práctica o, de algún modo, se rompen los principios de la POO.

Comment: Tal como está redactada tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Tal vez quieras preguntarla de otra forma, por ejemplo: ¿En qué casos se consideraría una mala practica ....?

Comment: Hola @RuslanLópez, gracias por la puntualización. haré lo que me comentas

Comment: No es buena idea por varios motivos: 1. El constructor es llamado de todos modos, aunque no tengas ninguno declarado; 2. El objeto se crea vacío (no utilizable de inmediato); 3. Luego de crear el objeto lo modificas (aplicando un *setter* sobre él), pudiendo tener impacto en el rendimiento; 4. Para informar el objeto con `N` campos tendrás que modificarlo `N` veces invocando a `N` *setters* (+ impacto en el rendimiento) ; 5. Si hay que hacer validaciones de ciertos campos ... ufff hay  que crear *setters* verbosos, cuando puedes centralizar todo eso en el constructor...

Comment: ... Y hay más cosas que se me escapan... En el caso que expones hay dos  soluciones mejores: 1. Usar constructores múltiples (en PHP no es tan simple como en otros lenguajes, pero tampoco es tan complicado... un poco más feo que en Java por ejemplo, pero es que PHP es así :) ); 2. O bien usar argumentos opcionales en el constructor; 3. O bien usar otra técnica (hay miles), dependiendo de la cantidad de campos que tenga la clase. Así te mantienes dentro del *estándar*, que es que la clase sea informada inicialmente por medio del constructor, y es mucho más fácil todo y performante así.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se rompe ningún principio de la POO, porque **¡aunque no declares un método constructor este es invocado de forma predeterminada!**. Aún así, lo normal es declarar un constructor en cada clase.

Por definición, el método constructor sirve para informar a la clase, o sea, para pasarle aquellos datos con los que el objeto debe ser inicializado.

En el caso que expones, si quieres atenerte al estándar habitual, podrías implementar el concepto de *constructor múltiple*, así, al crear el objeto le pasas uno, dos, tres ... parámetros según el caso. O bien podrías hacer uso de los *argumentos opcionales*.

Leyendo tu pregunta, creo que confundes un poco las cosas:

> Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que no declaro constructor y, de
>   este modo, al crear un objeto solo relleno las propiedades que
>   necesite en ese momento.

Dices eso y muestras un ejemplo de código en el que, mediante un *setter*, informas al objeto. Pero es que haciendo eso no rellenas las propiedades al crear el objeto, el objeto se crea primero vacío al hacer esto: `$publi = new Publicacion();`, porque el constructor es invocado siempre, aunque no lo hayas declarado en la clase. Lo que haces posteriormente es **modificar el objeto** previamente creado.

Solamente con la intención de arrojar un poco de luz sobre tus dudas, quiero enumerar algunas desventajas de hacer lo que pretendes, sin detenernos en un análisis exhaustivo de la situación:

1. El constructor es llamado de todos modos, aunque no tengas ninguno declarado. Por tanto, es una ilusión pensar que te ahorras algo no declarándolo;
2. Al no pasar datos por medio del constructor, para hacerlo luego mediante los *setter*, el objeto se crea vacío (no utilizable de inmediato);
3. Luego de crear el objeto lo modificas (aplicando un *setter* sobre él). Esto puede tener un impacto negativo en el rendimiento en contextos de uso concurrente o en objetos grandes.;
4. Para informar el objeto con `N` campos tendrás que modificarlo `N` veces invocando a `N` *setters*. Esto supone un impacto aún más negativo en el rendimiento. Pensando en un contexto real, es como vender un vehículo sin sus atributos básicos y luego hacer que el comprador vuelva al concesionario para dotar al vehículo de cada atributo... por cada atributo, un viaje al concesionario, implicando pérdida de tiempo, de dinero, de combustible, contaminación, etc, etc, etc.;
5. Si hay que hacer validaciones de ciertos campos ... ufff hay que crear *setters* verbosos, cuando puedes centralizar todo eso en el constructor.

## Algunas soluciones

### a) Constructor múltiple

En otros lenguajes declararías constructores múltiples únicamente creando los `N` constructores que necesites con sus parámetros, así, según el número de parámetros pasados se invocará el constructor correspondiente. En PHP esto es un poco más complicado, y un poco más feo, pero es que PHP es así :). Pero lo feo no quita lo efectivo.

Este es un ejemplo de constructores múltiples que hace uso de `func_get_args()` y de `func_num_args()`, el mismo está publicado en las [notas de contribución del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php#99903), con una amplia aceptación por parte de la comunidad de programadores:

```
class A 
{ 
    function __construct() 
    { 
        $a = func_get_args(); 
        $i = func_num_args(); 
        if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$f),$a); 
        } 
    } 

    function __construct1($a1) 
    { 
        echo('__construct with 1 param called: '.$a1.PHP_EOL); 
    } 

    function __construct2($a1,$a2) 
    { 
        echo('__construct with 2 params called: '.$a1.','.$a2.PHP_EOL); 
    } 

    function __construct3($a1,$a2,$a3) 
    { 
        echo('__construct with 3 params called: '.$a1.','.$a2.','.$a3.PHP_EOL); 
    } 
}
```

Aquí la clase `A` puede ser invocada de tres maneras distintas (pongo los mismos ejemplos del Manual de PHP):

```
$o = new A('sheep'); 
$o = new A('sheep','cat'); 
$o = new A('sheep','cat','dog');
```

### b) Usando argumentos opcionales o predeterminados

PHP permite el uso de lo que se llama en el Manual [***Valores de argumentos predeterminados***](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php). Esto permite que declares en el constructor de la clase argumentos que podrían ser pasados o no.

Si por ejemplo en tu clase el `$id` es obligatorio siempre, el constructor quedaría así:

```
class Publicacion
{
    private $id;
    private $usuario;
    private $fecha;
    private $titulo;
    private $contenido;

    public function __construct($id, $usuario=null, $fecha=null, $titulo=null, $contenido=null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        #Validar si los otros parámetros no son null para asignarlos
    }

}
```

Así declarada la clase, puedes crear instancias de la misma con 1,2,3 ó 4 parámetros:

```
$unaPublicacion=new Publicacion(1);
$unaPublicacion=new Publicacion(1,"elUsuario");
$unaPublicacion=new Publicacion(1,"elUsuario","laFecha");
$unaPublicacion=new Publicacion(1,"elUsuario","laFecha","elTitulo");
$unaPublicacion=new Publicacion(1,"elUsuario","laFecha","elTitulo","elContenido");
```

En vez de los argumentos opcionales, podrías usar también un array de argumentos y hacer las asignaciones en base a ese array.

Comment: Genial @A. Cedano! Como siempre perfectamente explicado. Además, por lo que veo en la opción B, incluso podría crear un constructor con todos los parámetros y asignarles un valor nulo a los que no requiera o no conozca su valor. Muchísimas Gracias!

Comment: Es correcto @ÁlvaroGarcía. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.